# How do I specify which column is the Foreign key and which column is the Primary Key on a one-to-many relationship. Using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship, one-to-many

I Have two tables like so

```
   public class Shepherd 
    {
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string UserId{ get; set; }
}

   public class Goat 
    {
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public string Hairyness { get; set; }
 public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to create the one-to-many relationship using the **Ids**  but I need to create a one-to-many relationship from Shepherd to many Goats using the **UserId** and '**CreatedBy**' columns.
I hope this makes sense. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: u may need fluentapi, u can check it out from here : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx   . it's allows you to pick which property is gonna be foreign key in the relation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BerkGarip but I need to specify the Primary Key (UserId) as well.

Comment: u can use ```[Key]``` attribute on upper of that PrimaryKey object.

Comment: Thanks again @BerkGarip but that seems to overwrite the Id which I need for another Table.

Comment: then you gonna use fluentapi to define foreign key in the relation. if you dont wanna deal with fluent api, then just name it in a right way and efcore will understand that object is foreign key for any object in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution! Using Linq.

```
    var goatPoo = from Goats in _context.Goats
              join Shepherd in _context.Shepherds
              on Goats.CreatedBy equals Shepherd.UserId
              where Shepherd.UserId == 77
              select new { 
                  Shepherd.Id, 
                  Shepherd.Firstname, 
                  Shepherd.Lastname, 
                  Goats.Hairyness
              };
```